# Which of two is better in file manipulation?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, tail, head

I have a file 'tbook1' with lot of numerical values (+2M). I have to perform the below in bash (Solaris / RHEL):

```
Do following:
Remove 1st and last 2 lines
Remove (,") & (")
Substitute (, ) with (,)
```

I can do it using two methods:

```
Method1:
sed -e 1d -e 's/,"//g' -e 's/, /,/g' -e 's/"//g' -e 'N;$!P;$!D;$d' tbook1 > tbook1.3

method2:
tail -n +2 tbook1 | head -n -2 > tbook1.1
sed -e 's/,"//' -e 's/, //' tbook 1.1 > tbook1.2
```

I want to know which one is better i.e. faster & efficient (resource usage) ?

Comment: Can you update the files in place?

Comment: no.. I can't do in-place... I have to keep the original 'tbook' intact !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 would usually be more efficient, mainly because of method 2's extra pipe and intermediate file that gets read and written to..

Answer (score 1):

Method one scans the file only once and writes 1 result (but please store the result in a file with different name)
Method two 2 scans the original file and the intermediate result and write the intermediate and the final result.  It is bound to be about twice slower.

Answer (score 1):

I think `head` and `tail` are more efficient for this line elimination task than pure `sed`. But the other two answers are also right. You should avoid running several passes.

You can improve the second method by chaining them together:

```
tail -n +2 book.txt | head -n -2 | sed -e 's/,"//' -e 's/, //'
```

Then `head` and `tail` are faster. Try it your self (on a reasonable sized file):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

target=/dev/null

test(){
        mode=$1
        start=$(date +%s)
        if   [ $mode == 1 ]; then
                sed -e 1d -e 's/,"//g' -e 's/, /,/g' -e 's/"//g' -e 'N;$!P;$!D;$d' book.txt > $target
        elif [ $mode == 2 ]; then
                tail -n +2 book.txt | head -n -2 | sed -e 's/,"//' -e 's/, //' > $target
        else
                cat book.txt > /dev/null
        fi

        ((time = $(date +%s) - $start))
        echo $time "seconds"
}

echo "cat > /dev/null"
test 0

echo "sed > $target"
test 1

echo "tail/head > $target"
test 2
```

My results:

```
cat > /dev/null
0 seconds

sed > /dev/null
5 seconds

tail/head > /dev/null
3 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks Juve, It seems I have a high perf server... :) ! I ran the above test on the file (quite big) and below is the result:

[root@cntosmhvtl2 prod]# ./perftest.sh
cat > /dev/null
0 seconds
sed > /dev/null
0 seconds
tail/head > /dev/null
0 seconds
[root@cntosmhvtl2 prod]# wc book.csv
   4230   71288 1244096 book.csv

Comment: I think I'll stick to sed version... seems like the Solaris servers do no't support the tail | head combo !!

Comment: Yes, the POSIX version of `head` does not accept a negative number after `-n`. @Marcos